# Notification Badges not woking in Android O

Tags: android, badge, android-8.0-oreo

With Android O developer preview google has introduced notification badges that are supposed to be shown on launcher icon. I am using emulator with Android O from dev channel.I wrote a simple code to show notification badge but it does not seem to work -

```
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .chooseBadgeIcon(Notification.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
                .setNumber(10)
                .build();

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

It just shows as normal notification.

API - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#chooseBadgeIcon(int)

Has anyone worked on this yet? Am I missing something?

Show badge is enabled in settings.

[image]

---

Tried with NotificationChannel too. Does not work -

```
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("TestBadge_id", "TestBadgeName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.setShowBadge(true);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);


    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .chooseBadgeIcon(Notification.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star)
                .setNumber(10)
            .setChannel("TestBadge_id")
                .build();

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: I cannot get this working on a Nexus 5X with the firmware images, even on a channel in which I opted into badges. My guess is that this is not implemented yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way with code to opt into badges that I am missing? I can try that if you could share a code snippet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a compatible launcher to make this work end-to-end. Being that there aren't any launchers that support this yet then you many not see the effects of this.

Comment: @AniketThakur: am referring to `setShowBadge(true)` on `NotificationChannel`, then use that channel when creating the `Notification`.

Comment: @Shmuel: I would hope that the launcher supplied with the Google APIs emulator and the hardware firmware builds would eventually support badges. I am surprised that they do not seem to do so already.

Comment: @CommonsWare agreed. But this is the situation it would seem. Frankly aosp launcher doesn't really matter to Google. They have the Google Now/ Pixel Launcher. I'm sure those will have support for icon badges eventually, possibly even before the aosp launcher

Comment: @Shmuel: "Frankly aosp launcher doesn't really matter to Google" -- AFAIK, that is now only on the non-Google APIs emulators. The Google APIs emulator (Android 7.0+) use some variation on the Pixel Launcher (round icons, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Notification badge examples of `Android-O` doesn't seem to work in emulator in early preview releases. But with the latest release of  Android-O developer **`preview-3`** the badges are displayed properly as documented in the [Notification Badges](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-badges.html) section.

To display notification badge, you need to set the [setShowBadge(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setShowBadge(boolean)) for a notification channel to `true`. By default badges will be displayed like below:

[image: Sample image to showcase badges]

Upon long press if there is a more than a one notification the count is displayed.The count automatically increments/decrements based on the active notifications. You can also adjust the count manually by using the  [Notification.Builder.setNumber()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setNumber(int)).

Sample showing notification count on long press of launcher icon:

[image: Badge notification showing count]

Make sure you are targetting the latest API:

```
compileSdkVersion 26 
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Tested in pixel Android emulator version `26.1.1`.

Comment: Following bizzard's answer, I am able to see Notification badge in emulator with Pixel Android API 26 configuration.
However, I neither specify [setShowBadge(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setShowBadge(boolean)) for a notification channel to true nor use [Notification.Builder.setNumber()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setNumber(int))