# Android notification badge dot not showing for custom firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, custom-notification

I have implemented custom view for firebase push notification. For custom view we need to remove "notification" key from push Json so that it can be handled even when app is closed like below:

```
{  
  "data": {
    "detail": {
     }
  },
  "to": "" 
}
```

For creating custom notification I used below code:

```
private void generateNotification(String title, String message, Intent intent) {
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationCount, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        /*
        * Custom notification layout
        * */
        String notificationHeaderText = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " \u2022 "
                + DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
        RemoteViews collapsedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_collapsed_notification);
        collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.timestamp, notificationHeaderText);
        collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.content_title, title);
        collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.content_text, message);

        RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_expanded_notification);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.timestamp, notificationHeaderText);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.content_title, title);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_message, message);

        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.footer_click);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_inkclick_logo_colored)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_INKCLICK)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                channel.enableLights(true);
                channel.setLightColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000/*, 500, 1000*/});
                channel.enableVibration(true);
                channel.setShowBadge(true);
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .build();
                channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            manager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
        else {
            manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
            }

        }
        notificationCount += 1;
    }
```

I have added `channel.setShowBadge(true);` after reading the official notification badge documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#java) as well as other answers on stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171297/notification-badges-not-woking-in-android-o) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000499/notification-badges-in-android-o).

I have also tried uninstalling the app and restarting the device but the badge is not showing.
Device is running on API 28(Pie).

Comment: Did you have any luck getting this to work? I am running into the same issue. The notification itself shows up fine, but no matter what I try, that notification dot will not appear.

Comment: @etrado I haven't found any solution yet. Still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style of the Android notification badge like this:

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

The overall code can look like this:

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_inkclick_logo_colored)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_INKCLICK)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Comment: Oh well.... hopefully you got your answer if no then please let me know.. I'll explain to you

Comment: I have edited your answer so that it's clearer. Next time, kindly pay attention, it is important to also add a bit of context if you're going to paste some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set style by adding below line

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

add this code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_inkclick_logo_colored)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_INKCLICK)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()) 
                .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the title or text (`setContentTitle` or `setContentText`). Because Android SDK uses it to describe notification in the window which appears when you long-click to the app icon. I don't know why this is not specified in the documentation, but it works this way.

[image: Lon-click notification window]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).